# Cannot control table width with CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have the following HTML (obtained from primefaces)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/selene/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces-aristo" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/selene/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.0" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/selene/javax.faces.resource/default.css.xhtml?ln=css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/selene/javax.faces.resource/ePruebas.css.xhtml?ln=css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/selene/javax.faces.resource/validation/validation.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.0"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/selene/javax.faces.resource/validation/beanvalidation.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.0"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      PrimeFaces.settings.locale = 'ca_ES';PrimeFaces.settings.validateEmptyFields = true;
      PrimeFaces.settings.considerEmptyStringNull = true;
    </script>
    <title>Título por defecto</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="cabecera" class="cabeceraDiv">
      <table id="j_idt10" class="ui-panelgrid ui-widget cabeceraGrid" role="grid">
        <tbody>
          <tr class="ui-widget-content" role="row">
            <td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell">Selene</td>
            <td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell">
              <label id="j_idt12" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></label>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id="principal">
      BIENVENIDO!
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and in `/myApp/resources/css` the css files

- default.css

  > div.cabeceraDiv {
  >    width: 100%;
  >   }
  >
  > .cabeceraGrid table{
  >    width: 100% !important;
  >   }
  >
  > .cabeceraGrid tr, .cabeceraGrid td {
  >    border-style: none !important;
  >   }
- ePruebas.css

  > .cabeceraGrid td, .cabeceraGrid tr {
  >     background-color: #FF7777;
  >   }

The issue I have is that I want to get the table (`j_idt10`) to use all of the space available in he div (which already is at 100%). As you can see, `cabeceraGrid` is one of the classes defined in the table, and it defines `width:100% !important`. Despite that, I still get a table that only has the size of the items inside it (112 px in this case).

What is more, when I go to inspect the `table` element  (Firefox 26), I get:

```
element {
}

.ui-panelgrid {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.ui-widget {
  font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

with no references to `cabeceraGrid` class at all!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you set it up on jsFiddle

Comment: Yeah, a fiddle would be great to solve this. Anyway, in anticipation, it's probably an issue with the display parameter of the table. Let's see if we can find a solution with the fiddle.

Comment: @dcc I'll think about it next time (there will be a next time since I usually struggle a lot with css).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below line will not apply to table with id 'j_idt10' as it means `table` elements ***inside*** elements with style class `cabeceraGrid`.

```
.cabeceraGrid table{ width: 100% !important; }
```

Use

```
.cabeceraGrid { width: 100% !important; }
```

or

```
.cabeceraDiv table{ width: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score -1):

element cabeceraGrid hasn't no table elements inside, cabeceraGrid is the table.

You need changue this in your css file.

```
default.css

    div.cabeceraDiv { width: 100%; }

    table.cabeceraGrid { width: 100% !important; } //here is the problem

    cabeceraGrid tr, .cabeceraGrid td { border-style: none !important; }

ePruebas.css

    .cabeceraGrid td, .cabeceraGrid tr { background-color: #FF7777; }
```

Comment: answering already answered question. Your answer is actually the same as the accepted answer. Downvote